# weird asp.net 'Server cannot access application directory...' error

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, windows-server-2003, sitecore

weird issue with visual studio 2010, right now i'm debugging a web application (which uses sitecore btw) and when entering in certain pages i get this error

```
Server cannot access application directory c:\svn\foo\trunk The directory does not exist or is not accessible because of security settings.
```

now the real fun part. `c:\svn\foo\trunk` is another asp.net project i worked on **months ago** on this same machine, with the same visual studio 2010, and they happen to both use sitecore too

besides those facts, the projects are absolutely not correlated. i deleted all the project files for `foo` eons ago

any idea what part of asp.net could be producing this error? what part does even know that i've used to work on this project?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to verify that your `hosts` file doesn't contain any strangeness, and likewise that your IIS instance doesn't contain any Applications that refer to your old codebase/directories.

Also, try running VS as administrator, and/or setting your user's permissions to admin rights.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a symbolic or junction link, make sure the folder that the symlink points to is still there.